# Split Table vertically based on condition

Tags: mysql, split, conditional-statements

I'm currently trying to split a table into multiple tables vertically based on the year.
My source table simply looks like this:

**Source Table:**

```
|----------------------|-------------------|
|         data         |        year       |
|----------------------|-------------------|
|          aaa         |         y1        |
|          bbb         |         y1        |
|          ccc         |         y2        |
|          eee         |         y2        |
|----------------------|-------------------|
```

What I'm trying to get is:

**year1:**

```
|----------------------|-------------------|
|         data         |        year       |
|----------------------|-------------------|
|          aaa         |         y1        |
|          bbb         |         y1        |
|----------------------|-------------------|
```

**year2**

```
|----------------------|-------------------|
|         data         |        year       |
|----------------------|-------------------|
|          ccc         |         y2        |
|          ddd         |         y2        |
|----------------------|-------------------|
```

The tricky part is, the number of years varies (up to 9 different years). This means I need to create an undefined number of tables conditionally, based on the amount of unique values in the column year. I'm using MySQL that doesn't enable IF or SELECT INTO queries, which is why I'm struggling to get this to work.

Comment: Is this just a display question or do you actually want to split the table into multiple ones? In the latter case, would not partitioning help?

Comment: It's the latter, however I haven't been able to make partitioning work.

Comment: @anthony If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. Otherwise write how you solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stored Procedure`:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE multiSelect ()
BEGIN
   DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE selectedYear year;
   DECLARE years CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT year FROM myTable;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
   OPEN years;
     getList: LOOP
          FETCH years INTO selectedYear;
          IF finished = 1 THEN LEAVE getList; END IF;
          SELECT * FROM myTable where year = selectedYear;
      END LOOP getList;
    CLOSE years;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cfrhWey8oVKGK83XELJCsb/6)

With `SP` you can create a `LOOP` and `FETCH` each result to create 1 or 9 years. 
All you have to do is `CALL multiSelect();`

Read more about `SP` [HERE](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-procedure.php)